# How to return a single variable from a whole function?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I would like to return a single variable from a whole function in python and use only that one variable in another python script. How would I go about in doing this. I have tried the following:

scripta:

```
def adding(self):
   s = requests.Session()
   test = s.get('url')
   print test.content 
   soup = BeautifulSoup(test.content,'html.parser')
   val = soup.find('input', {'name': 'id'})
   return val
```

So Script A gives me a value defined as `val`, I want to `import` only this value, however when I import script A into script B it runs the whole function including the `print test.content`. How would I go about doing this?

Script B:

```
from scripta import adding
```

Comment: Well if you want to have access to `val` in script B you have to run the function as some point ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute a partial function, it will execut the whole function. You have to remove the print line if you don't want it to be a part of the function.

Also, if you have code **outside the function** in `scripta`, you have to protect it with a `if __name__` clause to prevent it to be executed on import.

scripta.py:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def adding():
   s = requests.Session()
   test = s.get('url')
   # print test.content 
   soup = BeautifulSoup(test.content,'html.parser')
   val = soup.find('input', {'name': 'id'})
   return val

if __name__ == '__main__':
     # this part will only run if this is the main script. 
     # when starting scriptb first and importing this part won't run
     print adding()
```

scriptb.py:

```
from scripta import adding
result = adding() # the result variable will have what you returned (val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the function and store the result:

```
#Script A:
def adding():
    # remove "self" param, it is not used (and this does not 
    # seem to be a method of a class)
    # ...

#Script B:
from scripta import adding

xyz = adding()  # variable name does not matter
# do stuff with xyz
```

That's why you have the return statement in the first place. So you can communicate the value of the local variable elsewhere, and calling the function is the way to do that.